# Adding html in an if statement nested in a for loop

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have code like this in my razor index view:

```
@for (decimal hour=7m; hour<=20.5m; hour +=0.5m)
{
  var item = @Model.Items.FirstOrDefault( i=> i.Hour == hour);
  if (item != null)
  {
    <td colspan="@item.TimeBlocks">
      @item.Description
    </td>
    hour += (item.TimeBlocks-1)* 0.5m;
  }
  else
  {
    <td>
      <a href="/Items/Add/@Model.UserId">+</a>
    </td>
  }
}
```

For some reason, the VS2013 consistently tells me "} expected" in the Error List window.  The syntax highlighter shows everything highlighted fine until the curly brace right before the else.

I have tried using @: for the html tags.  It works fine in the if block, but in the else block I get the following error: 
":" is not valid at the start of a code block.

I have tried wrapping the html tags in a  tag as well, but that doesn't work either.

How would I do this to get it to render?

Comment: Are you sure your syntax for a `foreach` loop is correct?

Comment: @rexcfnghk - Typo when creating the question.  My code in VS is just for, not foreach

Comment: var item = @Model.Items.FirstOrDefault( i=> i.Hour == hour);  this line shouldn't have the @ symbol as you aren't outputting the result to the response stream

Comment: @Slicksim That was the problem!  You want to add that as an asnwer and I will accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a mistake in your code.

The following line

```
var item = @Model.Items.FirstOrDefault( i=> i.Hour == hour);
```

Should actually read:

```
var item = Model.Items.FirstOrDefault( i=> i.Hour == hour);
```

Removing that will fix your code